# Unauthorized (401) while using Jira API using Postman?

Tags: javascript, java, jira, postman, jira-rest-api

i am trying to access

```
get request url : https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=assignee=Unassigned

header : 
Authorization:Basic username:password
Content-Type:application/json
```

but response returned

```
Unauthorized (401)

Encountered a "401 - Unauthorized" error while loading this page.

Go to JIRA home
```

Kindly Help

Comment: Got same error in Postman, the issue is Authorization(jira login) not correct, after correction, API's working fine.

Answer (score 3):

401 means you're not authorized. So either your Authorization header is not correct, or your user does not have permission to view any issues , but in the latter case, you'd get a more specific error message.

Your authorization header should look something like this: `Authorization: Basic aHVwOmh1cA==`

The `username:password` part has to be BASE64 encoded.